# Setting shared_buffers over 320 MB prevents Postgres from restarting

Tags: postgresql, memory, configuration

I'm running Postgres 8.1 on a CentOS 5 system with 4 GB of RAM. Whenever I set `shared_buffers` above 320 MB, it won't run.

I've checked `SHMMAX` and it's at 4294967295 which is the max allowed for a 32-bit/4 GB system. Below are some of the other memory related settings:

```
max_connections = 225
shared_buffers = 327680
work_mem = 524288
max_fsm_pages = 500000
max_fsm_relations = 10000
```

Any suggestions on what could improve this?

Comment: *Postgres 8.1 on a CentOS 5 system*. There's your problem ;) . More seriously, check if anything else is locking a lot of shmem on the system.

Comment: Yeah, @CraigRinger is right - that system is so old it already has grandchildren...  Other than that, do you get an error message of some sort?

Comment: @dezso - I usually run `/etc/init.d/postgresql restart` and it just says "Failed" on the start. I've tried tweaking SHMAX but it doesn't do any good. (SHMAX is already set pretty high). I've reduced the number of `max_connections` down to 200, but still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a misunderstanding I guess. The unit for the given number is ***blocks*** (or buffers), not 1 kb like you assume.
Quoting [the manual for **`shared_buffers`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS):

> Each buffer is **8192 bytes**, unless a different value of BLCKSZ was
>   chosen when building the server.

Bold emphasis mine.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(327680 *  8192::numeric);

pg_size_pretty
--------------
2560 MB
```

Not 320 MB. In modern Postgres the syntax with appended unit is preferred: `320MB`, but I don't think that's implemented in the ancient Postgres 8.1, yet. For 320 MB set the GUC to:

```
shared_buffers = 40960
```

Have you considered installing a modern version of Postgres? (Like has been hinted in the comments ever so gently). [Postgres 8.1 was released 10 years ago.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Hey Erwin, Thanks for the clarification. When I'm at work tomorrow I will try that. Yes, I would like to upgrade Postgres on this server. Since it's a production server, I had to do it on the staging server first, which I finally did (a real ordeal since 8.1 doesn't work with pg_upgrade).

Comment: Thank you, Erwin. That fixed it. I still get really high CPU usage on queries but I guess that's a different thread.